# Sed move a line

Tags: linux, select, sed, line, move

I just need to move a line up in sed. I can select the line with

```
sed -i '7s///'
```

I need to move line 7 up 2 lines so it will be line 5.

I can't find anything on the internet to do this without complicated scripts, I can't find a simple solution of moving a specific line a specific number of times.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191838/sed-move-line-from-n-40-to-39-position

Comment: trying to move a line up with the answer chosen just inserts a blank line. maybe some explanation of the command? the answer doesn't have one either

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for moving a line _up_. However, `sed '3{h;d};6G'` will move a line _down_. Line 3 to line 6 in this example (the old line 6 becomes line 5). The second number (`6`) must be higher than the first (`3`).

Comment: Moving a line up is complicated, because `sed` works with *streams*, not files. You basically have to move an entire block of lines *down* instead. As a general rule, any time you see `sed -i`, consider using `ed` instead, which is designed to work with files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
seq 10|sed '5{N;h;d};7G'
```

when up to line 5 append next line(line 6) into pattern space then save them into hold space and delete them from pattern space; up to line 7 then append the hold space content("5\n6") behind the line 7; now, pattern space is "7\n5\n6";finally,sed will print the pattern space at the end of current cycle by default(if no "-n" parameter)

Comment: it is only a example

Answer (score 7):

`ed` is better at this, since it has a "move" command that does exactly what you want.  To move line 7 to be the line after line 4, just do `7m4`.  `ed` doesn't write the data back by default, so you need to explicitly issue a `w` command to write the data:

```
printf '7m4\nw\n' | ed input
```

Although it is perhaps better to use a more modern tool:

```
ex -s -c 7m4 -c w -c q input
```

Comment: Must... resist... urge.. to make joke about `ex` being more modern than `ed`.

Comment: @chepner and I can't resist: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html